# Adding costum font to android in font family xml

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-calendar, android-fonts

In the android guides for [Fonts in XML](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml.html), they give the example of font family XML you create by adding:

> android:font="@font/lobster_regular"

Which I think its the font you added to your assets/font folder. But when i try it I don't get it why it isn't able to find the font I've added. It only fins sans, serif and mono-space. Anyone have a clue what it might be the problem?

I know there are other ways to add a custom font, but due to the material calendar that I want to use, I need it to define in the styles XML, only way to customize it. I tried `calligraphy lib`, but does not help.

Comment: what about <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/roboto_medium</item>?

Comment: are you using Android Studio 3.0?

Comment: You need to add your font in `res/font`, not in the asset folder. I've followed [this tutorial](https://segunfamisa.com/posts/custom-fonts-with-android-support-library) together with the official documentation you've linked

Comment: Thanks this helped xD i need to use @assets/font Just like you guys said i just think the lib that im using is not working well and in the end it doesnt use the font i definded

Answer (score 1):

Using typeface you easily set font family

```
Typeface type = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
            "fonts/fontname");
```

now set this typeface to your textview

```
tv.setTypeface(type);
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your activity code:

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.appname);
Typeface face = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),
            "fonts/fontname");

tv.setTypeface(face);
```

Note that for this you'll have to create a fonts folder at `app/src/main/assets`